# How can i get first 100 rows , then next 100 rows , until you get all the records in cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I am having a table that has millions of records. I would like to purge the old data from these cassandra table.

the following is my table definition.

```
CREATE TABLE "Openmind".mep_notification (
    id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
    campaign uuid,
    created timestamp,
    flight uuid,
    read boolean,
    type text,
    user uuid
);

CREATE INDEX mep_notification_user_idx ON "Openmind".mep_notification (user);
```

how I can get first X number of rows at a time using cql. then the next X number and so on till i get all the rows from the table.

appreciate if you can help
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `limit` to get X numbers of rows. See the example bellow:

```
SELECT *
FROM cycling.rank_by_year_and_name 
PER PARTITION LIMIT 2;
```

*DataStax documentation:*
https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/cql/cql/cql_using/useQueryColumnsSort.html

If you trying to do a pagination, you can use the `Pagin`. Depending the program language you are using, you can check the rigth application to the `Pagin`.

*DataStax documentation*:
https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlshPaging.html

- In CQL prompt: https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.8/cql/cql/cql_using/search_index/cursorsDeepPaging.html
- In Java:
  https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.11/manual/paging/
- In PHP : https://datastax.github.io/php-driver/features/result_paging/
- In Spring Boot :
  https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current/reference/html/#reference